# Shell cp: cannot stat no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to use cp to copy files from one directory to another by globing

```
for files in index/*
do
  file=$(echo $files|cut -d'/' -f2)
  cp -r "$files" ".target/file"
done
```

However, cp will give this warning if the directory is empty. I tried 2>/dev/null to mute this message but it did not work. I wonder how I could fix it.

Comment: Set the `nullglob` option (`shopt -s nullglob`) such that the glob expands as the empty string instead of a literal `index/*`. Note that you don't use your `file`variable.

Comment: Not sure but maybe you want `".target/$file"` instead of `".target/file"`?

Comment: `file=${files#*/}` is a much faster way to strip the directory.

Comment: ...also more correct; `echo $files` is buggy. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this: (not tested)

```
find /index -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} .target/ \;
```

- `-maxdepth 1` : only look in this directory
- `-type f` : only take the files
- `-exec cp {} .target/ \;` : execute a "file copy" action

Comment: For GNU systems, you can do even better: `-exec cp -t ./target/ -- {} +` -- your current code starts a new copy of `cp` for each file; whereas `-exec ... {} +` fits as many files as possible onto each command line.

Comment: ...that said, if the OP really meant the `-r` (having directories as opposed to just files in `index/`), you might (1) want to do the same here; and (2) take off the `-type f`.